# cakephp 2.x auth component and angular js

Tags: cakephp, angularjs, authentication

I have a problem.

I would like to create an app using cakephp (backend) and angular js (frontend).

i don't have any idea about login users from angular js.

My code:

backend - appController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Cookie',
        'Auth' => array(
            //'loginRedirect'   => array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'home'),
            //'logoutRedirect'=> array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'home'),
                'authenticate'  => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields'    => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password', 'status' => 'enabled'),
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'scope'     => array('User.status' => 'enabled')
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public $helpers = array ('Html','Session','Js','Form');

}
```

backend - usersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {

        $this->Auth->allow('register');

        $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username'          => 'username',
            'password'          => 'secretword',
        );
    }

    public function login() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
                die("Logged");
            }
        }
        throw new ForbiddenException("You are not authorized to access that location.");

    }
```

frontend - userSv

```
var login = function(data) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var params = {
        "params":{
            "plugin":null,
            "controller":"users",
            "action":"login",
            "named":[],
            "pass":[],
            "isAjax":false              
        },
        "data":{"User":{"username":data.username,"password":data.password}},
        "query":[],
        "url":"users\/login",
        "base":"",
        "webroot":"\/",
        "here":"\/users\/login"
    };

    console.log(params);

    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/users/login',data:params}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("success");
        //console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(config);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error");
        //console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(config);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

so, after sent the information, i get:

"You are not authorized to access that location.

Error: The requested address '/users/login' was not found on this server."

do you have any idea?

Comment: i don't have any idea about security component... i'm using auth component.

Comment: In comments, always use @username (only the OP is always being notified, [see help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)) to make sure the user gets notified! Anyways, after having a second look, I was a little mislead, so forget my initial comment. Looks more like the problem is that you've set the password field to be a field named `secretword`, but in your AJAX request you are sending it as `password`. That being said, check that your controller actually receives the expected data (`$this->request->data`).

Comment: allow login action, please check your "rout" and after be care of your "password" field's name (secretword).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code that has an Angular app making JSON requests to a backend CakePHP server and the authentication is handled by a plugin. I think it is exactly what you are looking for. One caveat is that I don't use the inbuilt CakePHP Auth component, I wrote my own.

[Here](https://github.com/rameshpa/angular-cakephp-auth) is the code and the [ReadMe](https://github.com/rameshpa/angular-cakephp-auth/blob/master/README.md) has the concepts.